# Change ffmpeg output directory

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg

Im using ffmpeg to compress footage and i want to compess the footage of a specific day but when i overwrite the files it outputs a empty stream because it writes as it reads at the same time so i want to rename the output file. Find will give the full path which is necessary but i don't know how to change the actual file name, rather than the path.

Any suggestions?

```
find /home/server/recordings/compress -name '*.mp4' -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} ffmpeg -i {}  -c:v libx265 -preset fast -crf 25 -x265-params "vbv-maxrate=1500:vbv-bufsize=1000" -c:a aac {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass file names to `sh` using `-exec` and modify the filename there. For example:

```
find /home/server/recordings/compress -name '*.mp4' -exec sh -c '
ffmpeg -i "$1" -c:v libx265 -preset fast -crf 25 -x265-params "vbv-maxrate=1500:vbv-bufsize=1000" -c:a aac \
    "${1%/*}/modified_${1##*/}"
' _ {} \;
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining a little on how i can use it or what to do with it?

Comment: @Filip you can just copy and paste it to your terminal

Comment: It runs a shell script for each mp4 file in `/home/server/recordings/compress`. In the shell script files can be referenced by `$1`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Do you know a good site that explains it a bit more? "${1%/*}/modified_${1##*/}" ' _ {} \; That is the part i don't understand but i know now how to use it!

Comment: @Filip google *linux shell scripting tutorial*, *linux find command examples* etc., there are a lot of tutorials on them. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

The last argument in ffmpeg is the output filename. So you can change your command to

```
find /home/server/recordings/compress -name '*.mp4' -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} ffmpeg -i {}  -c:v libx265 -preset fast -crf 25 -x265-params "vbv-maxrate=1500:vbv-bufsize=1000" -c:a aac {}.out
```

This way all the output files will have .out appended.